# What is the error in my SQL query with Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to retrieve data from SQL Server database using python but the system crash and display the below error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 

search_term=st.text_input("Enter Search Term")
cursor.execute("select * from testDB.dbo.t1 where ID = ? OR where  first =?",search_term,search_term) 
                                
dd = cursor.fetchall()
print(dd)
```

Comment: `where ID = ? OR where  first =?` you got an extra "where"

Comment: but my query must search for column name "ID" or Column name "first"

Comment: A query scope only has one `WHERE`, @khaledM_dev . Have a look at the [examples documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and you'll see the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `where` clauses. There should be only one `where` clause, which can have as many conditions joined by logical operators as you want:

```py
cursor.execute("select * from testDB.dbo.t1 where ID = ? OR first =?", search_term, search_term)
```

Comment: i tried  your answer now i have this below error:
`DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test5' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: where the ID is int but the other column is nvarchar

Answer (score 1):

You've added an extra `WHERE` to your clause.

The correct way to write it is:

`cursor.execute("select * from testDB.dbo.t1 where ID = ? OR first = ?",search_term,search_term)`

Also, if you're writing SQL statements directly, without using an ORM, I'd suggest to connect to your DB directly and testing the query there, so it'll be easier to find and debug errors.
If you want a great free alternative, and uses Mac, I suggest [Postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/)